# close system call definition in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, system-calls

My native language is not English. So I got problems when I read the document. In man page of `close` in FreeBSD: `close - delete a file descriptor`. And in Linux man page, `close() closes a file descriptor, so that it no longer refers to any file.` I'm wondering are they the same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. The FreeBSD version is unfortunate given what `delete` came to mean in C++.

Comment: All right. Thanks for your reply @EJP